# Leak at Main Shut Off Valve

Tags: plumbing, leak

I've dealt with a little bit of plumbing fixing toilet valves, but now my main water shut-off valve seems to be leaking in a very particular spot. Not sure what steps I should take to resolve this one or at least remedy it in the near future. I'm going to try duck taping it, but I just wondering if there is something else I should be doing.

[image: Image of the Leak]

Comment: Is this before or after the meter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Duck" or duct tape is pointless here. You MIGHT get some temporary slowdown from using a self-fusing silicone overwrap, but it's not a solution, and will be difficult to use effectively on an active leak, especially with an elbow involved.

You need to contact your water company and arrange for the water to be shut off from outside the house so this can be fixed correctly. If you get lucky they might be responsible for the pipe up to the shutoff valve.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to contact the city to have the municipal water shut off while the repair is made. A leak like this can quickly get worse and before you know it, your entire house can be flooded with no way to shut off the water.

If the leak gets worse and you can't get a hold of the city, you can call the city police on their non-emergency number and they can usually get someone down to shut the water off for you.

You appear to have a 3/4" supply pipe that is reduced down to 1/2" before the shutoff. You also have a threaded connection on the main line which is another potential point of failure.

I'm not a fan with how they originally installed it. It would be better to have a ball valve installed right to the stub coming out the floor instead of how it is now. Then you could reduce it down to 1/2", hook up the meter, etc.