# valve leak at main water supply

Tags: plumbing, leak

I'm not sure if this is the same question as [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62622/leak-at-main-shut-off-valve), but I'll ask anyway.

I have a leak near the knob at my main water supply.  The picture shows the green oxidation. Is there any DIY solution, or do I need to call a plumber/municipality? If I just call the water company to shut the line off to the house could I replace the handle and nut myself?

I don't have a water pressure regulator for this line.  The water meter often makes an audible ticking noise.  Can water pressure that is too high cause this kind of leak?  I don't know what the pressure actually is, but I can buy a gauge.

[image]

EDIT: the other thing is the 2 black wires behind the valve....what are they?  and if i use a channel-lock and accidentally contact with the exposed areas of the wire, then what?  scary no??

Comment: A lot of older mechanical type water meters make a ticking noise when water is running through them.  There's something like a paddle, or rudder that moves back and forth with water flow, and the back and forth motion drives the meter itself.  This design, if it has problems, usually doesn't cause high water meter readings.

Comment: @SteveSh but can high water pressure cause a valve leak?

Comment: The wire is a ground wire, since that's a ground clamp to a metal water line, though it should be green or bare, not black, unless it's larger than it seems to be (AWG4 or bigger) in which case it should be green-taped at connections. **That EDIT should actually be a whole new question, though, as it's unrelated to the leak.** And you *really should use* an open-end wrench on the packing nut, not channel-locks.

Comment: @Ecnerwal kind of, but it's also related to water i suppose..water leak becoming bigger then shorting the "ground wire..." but why is there a wire there at at?? lol...as you can SEE it's actually 2 black wires, not 1....sorry bad pic i guess...

Comment: @Ecnerwal  i should open a new question....i'm confused...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible to just replace parts/washers in the valve itself, instead of the whole valve.

First try tightening the nut below the handle a bit, might be all you need.

Have the water turned off, open a faucet at a sink to relieve pressure.

Undo the nuts on top of the valve and take the insides to a plumbing/hardware/big box store to get the right parts.

Would be an decent to have hot water heater turned off and have the hot water heater valves off also.

Comment: Yeah, this is just leaking around the valve packing. Quite possibly 1/12-1/4 turn of the packing nut will solve it for now with no need to shut anything off. Repacking is easy, other than the inconvenience of getting your water line shut off. If going to that bother, I'd replace it with a ball (1/4 turn) valve as they do better at sitting open for years and still closing when you want them to.

Comment: @Ecnerwal yes! this works...no more leak...

Comment: this answer is correct, but still somewhat confusing...